# What's the optimal html link syntax to use for site icons/favions?

Tags: html, cross-browser, hyperlink, favicon

Which should I use:

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Or:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
```

I've seen both in use and both work in a lot of current browsers - but which is more consistently supported by the most browsers?

Comment: This is a valid question. Why close it?

Comment: @kazanaki - beats me. Probably because I answered my own question (5 days after I asked it) and some users really don't like that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK, figured this out for myself...

**rel**

`<link rel="icon"` will work in IE8, 9, FX and Chrome but not in IE6 or 7. The `rel="shortcut icon"` is supported by IE6 & 7.

The W3C standards state a space delimited list and that the key is just `icon`. This means `shortcut icon` works in all browsers - handled incorrectly by IE and as a compound key in everything else.

**type**

All browsers appear to accept and handle the Windows icon format for the file.

IE expects this to be served as MIME type `image/vnd.microsoft.icon` but only seems to consistently work if the content type is `image/x-icon`.

Everything else expects `image/ico` but pretty much ignores it.

---

So the best format is:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

However if IE has problems handling the file or your server is not passing the `image/x-icon` content type in the headers it can help to specify the IE expected type:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was tired of resizing favicons manually, and then having to create multiple `<meta>` and `<link>` tags for each size, and also using the correct template tags for the web framework I was currently using.

So I wrote a free little tool for generating all the correct sizes, and also for generating the markup required. Check it out at https://favicongenerator.co

Comment: Awesome tool, resolved all my problem with specifics browsers